# CR2032 replacement

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I'm looking for a part that can be placed into CR2032 housing (instead of the CR2032 battery) and gets the power to the pins (through some external wires/connector).

In other words, I would like to power the device, which is powered by 3V coin cell battery, with AC/DC 110/220V->3V adapter, without the need to solder wires to internal device pins.

Is there such thing?

Update: Thank you for pointing in comments that it is a 3V battery (not 1.5V as I initially put it in the question).

Comment: Yes there is. They are called battery emulators but they don't work directly from mains. And CR2032 is 3V battery, not 1.5V.

Comment: you could probably make one ... a scrap PCB should yield two circular pieces of PCB material with copper on one side

Comment: The CR2032 coin cell outputs about 3 V, not 1.5 V.   I do this trick all the time, you just need a 3mm or 1/8" thick piece of material like plywood, put conducting copper tape on each side, solder on wires, and off you go. But mark it clearly to be sure you don't insert it upside down.

Comment: @jsotola With some coin cell holders the (+) contact touches the _side_ of the can instead of the bottom face of it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you are correct ... make a groove on the edge of the disk and wrap some wire around to create a conductive edge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search for CR2032 dummy battery or CR2032 battery eliminator.

Some have glued a couple cheap-ish custom ENIG PCBs together to make up the 3.2mm thickness.